# How to use jquery to shift focus to scrollbar

Tags: javascript, jquery-selectors, focus, jquery

I am using select with onchange event. when user selects an item in select, I am loading content below using jquery post. It works fine. But the focus remains on the select, when I use down arrow on keyboard to scroll down, the select changes loading different content.

I want to know how I can shift focus from select to scrollbar after the change event.

I appreciate any help.

Comment: similar kind of post can be found http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7288565/lose-focus-from-select-box-with-jquery-change-event. possible duplicate

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to focus the scrollbar (I don't even know wheter it's possible). All you have to do is lose focus on your select.

So inside your onchange handler:

```
$(this).trigger('blur');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can on succes of Jquery post request 
place

```
 $('#select').next().focus();
```

**Example :**

```
          $.ajax 
                ({
                    type: "GET",
                    url: URL
                    success: function (html)
                    {
                      // your code here 
                      $('#select').next().focus();
                    }
                });
```